# Returning multiple arrays of distinct values in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Given documents like this:

```
{
  "Damage": 
    { 
      "Cause_of_Damage": ["Weather"],
      "Category": ["High"]
    }
}
```

This query returns an array of distinct values, and it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE i
FROM c
JOIN i IN c.Damage.Cause_of_Damage
```

How can I add the `"Category"` property in a similar way and return both as arrays of distinct values? Desired example result:

```
{
  "cause": ["Weather"],
  "category": ["High"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your requirement?

```
SELECT Array(SELECT DISTINCT VALUE i
FROM c
JOIN i IN c.Damage.Cause_of_Damage) as cause,
Array(SELECT DISTINCT VALUE j
FROM c
JOIN j IN c.Damage.Category) as category
FROM c
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "cause": [
            "Weather"
        ],
        "category": [
            "High"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thats a promising start, but this gives me many result documents instead of just one, it returns one result document for every distinct value. Is there a way to consolidate all distinct values into arrays of a single result document?

Comment: Actually, is it possible this join query seems to creates a cross product of all joined results? That would be a huge amount of result entries.

Comment: I see.As far as I know,this couldn't be achieved by a call through sql.You need to make two call.

Comment: Thats what I feared. Thanks!

Comment: Btw if you clarify in your response that it is not really possible to do in one document then I can mark your answer as accepted.